# How to change cursor color without changing text color?

Tags: html, css

I want to have the cursor `#FFF` while my font is `#000`.

Is that possible?

Comment: The cursor generally **is** white. Are you sure you mean 'cursor'?

Comment: Do you mean the caret inside a text box?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[You can make a custom one](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/).

```
input, textarea {
    cursor: url(cursor.cur);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From the mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color)

```
/* Keyword values */
caret-color: auto;
caret-color: transparent;
caret-color: currentColor;

/* <color> values */
caret-color: red;
caret-color: #5729e9;
caret-color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
caret-color: hsla(228, 4%, 24%, 0.8);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's easy. Set your font color normally then use a custom cursor.

http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

That does depend on wether the custom cursor can be color, I'm just assuming it can be.

Answer (score 3):

to [change caret color CSS](http://guruquest.net/question/how-to-change-caret-color-css-of-a-cursor-in-input-textbox-or-textarea/) of input type text and textarea use below css

```
input,textarea {
     color: #8f0407;
     text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000 ;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent ;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
     textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #ccc;
     text-shadow: none;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/bhaskars11/pen/apdJEd)

Comment: Answer is good. It is working fine in chrome. But it is not working in internet explorer

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<style>
input {
  color: rgb(60, 0, 248);  /* change [input cursor color] by this*/
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #D60B0B; /* change [input font] by this*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```