# Is there any way to change JUST the color of the textarea cursor without changing the font color?

Tags: jquery, css, textarea

I want to have a function for my website that lets users tag other users/articles. But, anchor tags are not supported inside textareas. So, I set the background to transparent for the textarea and places a div beneath it. On the keyup event, the div is populated with the value of the textarea. The only problem is that the user can't see the cursor since it's transparent. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - How to change cursor color without changing text color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615681/css-how-to-change-cursor-color-without-changing-text-color)

Comment: Um, not really. The solution for that question didn't work because I need the cursor to blink like it normally would in a textarea. I just need the cursor and font colors to be different.

Comment: well, you can create your own animated (blinking) cursor (.ani) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via CSS...
check the link http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

```
input, textarea {
    cursor: url(cursor.cur);
}
```