# How to change blinking cursor/caret in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have a `textarea` with transparent text, with an underlying `pre` that displays the text via js, so it looks like the user is typing dynamic text as they go. It works on the same concept as the background colors [on this Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/), except I'm changing text color and background color, so I want transparent text in the textarea.

However, defining the `textarea`'s color as transparent, also makes the blinking cursor transparent, which is disorienting. Is there a way to only change the blinking cursors color or only change the text's color and not affect the blinking cursor?

I have browsed other questions, but they haven't provided sufficient answers.

Note: I am referring to the blinking textarea caret, not the mouse cursor. When you click in a textarea or a text input, a blinking textarea "cursor" or caret pops up. This question is about that, not about the mouse cursor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092963/can-i-change-the-blinking-caret-in-a-form-text-area-in-a-browser

Comment: That question is from 2011, with one unaccepted answer of "The simple answer is you can't..." @akash Note the last line in my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682587/is-there-any-way-to-change-just-the-color-of-the-textarea-cursor-without-changin

Comment: what about this one ?

Comment: Jeez, I originally went over other questions on this site that I had looked at and why they don't work, but took it out because I wasn't sure it was relevant. Both of those refer to the mouse cursor, not the textarea caret. Click in a textbox, like the "add comment" box. That flashing bar where you're typing is what I'm talking about.

Comment: I guess they posted these links as comments since you can't downvote a comment... @JamesG. take a look at my answer, let me know if you still need help with this - I had the same problem just now and this is one of the first pages that come up in google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution, but working only if you use a monospaced font (like Courier or Courier New) - don't set textarea's color to transparent, but on *keyDown* fill it with spaces insead of any other characters:

```
on keyDown ↓
get the character ↓
put it in the underlaying <pre> tag ↓
put a space in the textarea
```

You would need to get the caret position to place the space and the character in appropriate place, but there are scripts for that already ([this one](http://www.examplet.org/jquery/caret.php) for example).

I can create a fiddle/plunkr example for you if you want.

The thing is getting harder if the font you are using is not monospaced, but sice you are using a `<pre>` tag you should be ok with this one (if anyone is curious I can describe the non-trivial, time consuming and definately not-IE-compatible approach for not monospaced fonts I came up with).

EDIT:
Actually you can also get the caret position from the transparent textarea and move a 1px-wide black div to the correct position (for not monospaced fonts). You can also blink it using CSS animations or Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

try the css property caret-color

docs here: [w3schools - caret color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_caret-color.asp)

```css
textarea {
  caret-color:red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```