# Change cursor color of focused input

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can you change the color of the text-cursor on an input field? There must me some sort of JavaScript trickery for this. I can't seem to find anything reliable.

e.g:

```
<input name="input" type="text" />

input {
    color:red;
}
```

How do I keep the text red, but change the color of the cursor? here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n2898/

Comment: I don't believe you can change the color of the cursor

Comment: This question has already been answered. [How to change cursor color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615681/how-to-change-cursor-color-without-changing-text-color)

Comment: In general, leave the cursor alone. But yeah, you can't change the cursor color without a custom one. Also, are you sure you don't mean the caret instead of cursor?

Comment: so is this how jsfiddle do it? e.g when you click on a colored syntax the cursor remains black??

Comment: since cursor is not an HTML element, I dont think you can manipulate that. The reason you can do this (different cursors, example. loading, text, hover ... ) : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp is because the html elements are changed so that browser will act accordingly to show different types of cursors.