# Change textarea blink typing mark's color

Tags: javascript, css

```
<textarea style="color:red;"></textarea>
```

I have a textarea set color red. However I want the blinking mark be black, so user can see more clear where they are typing.

Is anyway to do achieve this? Do I need to use javascript, if so, please tell me how?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615681/how-to-change-cursor-color-without-changing-text-color

Comment: By any chance, have you looked at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615681/how-to-change-cursor-color-without-changing-text-color) [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324434/change-textarea-cursor-color-in-the-textarea)?

Comment: i don't think you can control them separately , but do tell if you find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
textarea {
 cursor: url(cursor.cur);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Implementing Custom Cursors**
>
> If you need a cursor that is not included by default, or not supported
>   across all browsers, you have the option to include a custom cursor
>   image. This can be defined similarly to the font-family rule, where
>   you provide fallbacks in case the custom cursor doesn't load.

```
.elementClass {
    cursor:     url(/cursors/cursor.png), /* Modern */
            url(/cursors/cursor.cur), /* IE  */
            default; /* Built-in fallback */
}
```

[More Info here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-css-cursor-rule--webdesign-9441) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url)

Comment: Caret, not cursor. Different things

Comment: oh, I misunderstood the question @timeNomad... thanks

Comment: @timeNomad - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74548/is-caret-a-widely-understood-word